# Does Hover while flying require any action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, flight

In today's game it came up that combat start so I cast shield and flew towards combat. In the next round I wanted to cast enlarge person which is 1 round, however I was already flying. Clearly I wasn't able to spend an action to move if I was going to still cast the spell, but under the [fly skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly) there is no mention as to the action cost of hover. Since all other movement options clearly require movement and are thus part of an action with movement.

Also, in case it matters, I was not under the effect of a fly spell, but magical insect wings which acts like part of my body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, it doesnt.

The [Fly](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/fly.html) skill page says it requires no action, the check should be taken as part of another action or reaction to a situation:

> Action
>
> None. A Fly check doesn’t require an action; it is made as part of another action or as a reaction to a situation.

You will notice that a hover check is required when you ignore the minimum movement required to remain flying, which includes *not moving* (or hovering):

> Without making a check, **a flying creature can remain flying at the end of its turn so long as it moves a distance greater than half its speed**. It can also turn up to 45 degrees by sacrificing 5 feet of movement, can rise at half speed at an angle of 45 degrees, and can descend at any angle at normal speed. Note that these restrictions only apply to movement taken during your current turn. At the beginning of the next turn, you can move in a different direction than you did the previous turn without making a check. **Taking any action that violates these rules requires a Fly check.**

Note that monsters have a [specific feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/hover/) on the bestiary to allow them to hover without making skill checks. This means that even creatures with a natural (or magical) *fly speed* still need to make Fly checks, even to make a full-round attack or take a 5-foot step while flying.

Answer (score -1):

As the normal questioning about hover is whether a flying character *has* or *can* hover in order to get permission to remain airborne and take other actions like casting a spell or attacking, it is logical to assume the inverse applies - that if you already have hover, it, being the desperately sought status because it doesn't require an action, therefore has no action cost to the economy.

I'm not even sure it counts against the free action in the action economy, any more than "standing" does. So if you had a power than manifests as a free action that counted toward the GM limit of free actions, I don't believe that hover counts toward that imposed total as discussed here:
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/unchained-rules/unchained-action-economy/

HOWEVER, while the fly spell defaults as non-moving levitation (i.e., hover), a winged character does not automatically get the hover ability unless the power or racial description states it does.

if the racial ability or spell is newer material or exotic, home brew, etc., then it is up to the DM to determine if the winged ability to fly includes the ability to hover in place.